# How to deploy a heroku app containing a forked github repo

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, react-window

I have a `Node` app that is running on `heroku`.

Now I want to make some changes to the package `react-window` that I'm using (the first time that I'm trying this)

So I forked the `react-window` repo and replaced the original packgage using:

```
yarn remove react-window

yarn add https://github.com/myusername/react-window.git
```

When I build this on my local machine, everything is fine and the forked packages is used.

But when I try to deploy it on `heroku` the build fails and I get this error:

```
error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel/runtime/-/runtime-7.0.0.tgz: Extracting tar content of undefined failed, the file appears to be corrupt: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/tmp/yarncache.wxh1C/v4/npm-@babel-runtime-7.0.0-adeb78fedfc855aa05bc041640f3f6f98e85424c/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncIterator.js'"
```

I tried to point to a specific branch, but this also does not work:

```
yarn add https://github.com/myusername/react-window.git#master
```

When I reinstall the original package, everything is fine again.

So my **question**: what is the right way to add a forked package when deploying to `heroku`?